# How to add external libraries in to my android camera application using Android Studio?

Tags: android, image, crop

In my Camera Application, i have to use editors(crop,rotate,contrast,sharpen) for images. Some tutorials will say by using some **libraries** will support those features. But there is no clear description about how the library files will include within the project.

Send me any easiest and clear description of including external library inside my android application.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html#ReferencingLibraryModule

Comment: I am looking for Image Cropping tool without using default croppers of android like gallery or Google+ croppers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**file->project Structure->app-> Dependencies**

[image]

Comment: ya i got this dependency "**com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1**". but , i don't know that what is the next step to do for getting cropper tool and include library of **soundcloud** inside the project.